# Does adding a file change its modification time?

Tags: file, ftp

I am working on a website that reads out an FTP directory for files, and does something with them depending on their modification date. I do not have much experience with FTP so my question is if uploading files, pictures to be exact, changes their modification date to the time where they were uploaded?